# Rails - generate a Scaffold within a Namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces

I have an early stage project that I am trying to namespace before organization becomes a problem, following the most clear and up to date [post](http://blog.makandra.com/2014/12/organizing-large-rails-projects-with-namespaces/) I can find regarding namespacing.

But it doesn't work as magically as I'd hoped. How do I generate a Scaffold within a Namespace that is functional? I believe this is an issue of plurality vs. singularity.

Example:

```
words
  languages
  definitions

users
```

Generate:

```
rails g scaffold Words/Language name:string
rails g scaffold Words/Definition name:string
rails g scaffold Word name:string language:references definition:references user:references
```

After the above, there is an exception for `word.language` but not `word.user`:

```
irb(main)> word = Word.find(1)
  Word Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Word id: 1, name: "Hello", language_id: 1, definition_id: 1, user_id: 1>

irb(main)> word.user
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<User id: 1, name: "admin">

irb(main)> word.language
NameError: uninitialized constant Word::Language
```

Rails generates two models, both `word.rb` and `words.rb`:

app/models/word.rb

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :language
  belongs_to :definition
  belongs_to :user
end
```

app/models/words.rb

```
module Words
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'words_'
  end
end
```

How do I combat this issue of singular vs. plural with namespaced generated scaffolds?

Comment: Is the scaffold generator intended to support namespaces?

Answer (score 1):

## A Second Attempt

In the linked guide, it's suggested to put the controller into a plural namespace, to allow for nested folder structure for views. The model should however remain singular, so my second attempt is to generate the `model` first in the singular namespace, and then the `scaffold_controller` passing the singular model with `--model-name=`.

Generate:

```
rails g model Word/Language name:string
rails g scaffold_controller Words/Language name:string --model-name=Word/Language

rails g model Word/Definition body:text
rails g scaffold_controller Words/Definition name:string --model-name=Word/Definition

rails g model Word name:string language:references definition:references user:references

rails g scaffold_controller Word name:string language:references definition:references --model-name=Word
```

The route in question:

```
namespace :words do
  resources :definitions, :languages
end
resources :words
```

This time the error is `undefined local variable or method 'new_word_definition_path'`.

This is because the correct route is `new_words_language` according to `rake routes`.

This returns me to the initial question of how to overcome this plurality confusion.